# two-way UART communication between STM32 and ESP32 works :) But I would like to understand more what happens

Tags: c, stm32

Right now, I am in process of learning STM32 and have some struggles with C (I am beginner level - Knowing some basics). I was trying for about 2 days to figure out how to communicate with UART and somehow with thousands forum questions and answers I made it. The problem is I do not understand some parts of code: specifically what "(uint8_t*)&x" and "&x" means. Have some idea, but I am 0% sure. Below is STM32 UART part of code (without UART Init):

```
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      if (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1, UART_FLAG_RXNE) == SET) {
          HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1,&x,1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
          x++;
          for (i=0; i<x; i++){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_Delay(100);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_Delay(100);
          }
          HAL_Delay(1000);
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t*)&x,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
```

I saw somewhere someone mention pointers. As I said I am not experienced with C enough, so It would be nice If someone can recommend me where I could look to understand it more. Thank you!

Since I saw a lot of people are searching for this way of two-way communication I will put both STM32 and ESP32 codes in "What did you try and what were you expecting?" session so somebody can use it in there projects.

STM32 code:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */
  int i;
  char x = 0;
  //char y = 5;
  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  for(i=0;i<5;i++){
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
          HAL_Delay(300);
          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
          HAL_Delay(300);
      }
  HAL_Delay(3000);
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
      if (__HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart1, UART_FLAG_RXNE) == SET) {
          HAL_UART_Receive (&huart1,&x,1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
          x++;
          for (i=0; i<x; i++){
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);
              HAL_Delay(100);
              HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
              HAL_Delay(100);
          }
          HAL_Delay(1000);
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,(uint8_t*)&x,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL4;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

ESP32 code (MicroPython):

```
from machine import UART
from time import sleep

x = b'\x01'
uart1 = UART(1, baudrate=9600, tx=19, rx=18)

while 1:
    uart1.write(x)
    while uart1.any()==0:
        pass
    x = uart1.read(1)
    print(x)
    print(int.from_bytes(x, "big"))
    sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: *"I saw somewhere someone mention pointers. As I said I am not experienced with C enough, so It would be nice If someone can recommend me where I could look to understand it more. Thank you!"* - indeed I can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list. You need from the book, exercise on your PC, then when proficient start programming embedded systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“&x” is taking the address of “x”.  It is the equivalent of making a pointer to “x”.

Once you have that pointer to “x” it is a pointer to x’s type.  In this code that type is char.  Presumably your function HAL_UART_Transmit is looking for a pointer to a variable of type uint8_t, so your code uses “(uint8_t*)&x” to cast the pointer to type char to a pointer of type uint8_t.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely need to learn more about pointers and memory addressing.